# Ignore unique validation while update data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my products table `product_name` is unique. If i don't update the product name while updating the data, it won't let me update my product information and shows the following error:

> product name has already been taken

How can I ignore the unique name while updating same product?
Here is the code i have used for updating:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
     $product = Product::find($id);     
     $this->validate($request, [ 
         'product_name'=> 'unique:products,product_name,'.$product->id ,          
     ]);  
     $product->product_name = Input::get('product_name'); 
     $product->product_unit_price = Input::get('product_unit_price');
     $product->save();         
     return Redirect::to('products');
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the name you're setting is not actually already taken by another row in the database? What you're doing *should* work according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates). Also, make sure you get the `$id` correct.

Comment: The rule seems OK, are you sure you're getting the ```$id``` and having the product with the same id?

Comment: I think it should be `'product_name'=> 'unique:products,product_name,'.$product->id.',id'`

Comment: $id is correct. I checked it several times

Answer (score 2):

if you are using just the `unique` validation rule then you can use:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'product_name' => Rule::unique('products')->ignore($product->id),
              ]);
```

Or if you have other validation rules too then use this way:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'product_name' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('products')->ignore($product->id),
             ],
     ]);
```

But include `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;` before using it.

Comment: I used your both solution but same message i'm getting `product name has already been taken`

Comment: you have a column as `product_name` column in the database?

Comment: Yes ..the name is ok

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have use **use Illuminate\Http\Request**...with correct table field name and input name.

```html
$request->validate([
    'product_name' => 'required|unique:products,product_name,'.$product->id,
]);
```